# I want to setup Active directory in Ubuntu server for mix environmet (Windows/linux) to authenticate

Tags: server

I want to migrate my all windows Server and workstation to linux system (Ubuntu server 12.04). I am new to Linux.

I want to create Active directory for my Linux (Ubuntu) as well as Windows Workstations to work parallel (Some system will have Ubuntu workstation and some Windows 7).

Now i need assistance to which application would help me to achieve this and what would be the perquisite. Needed best procedure to install and maintain the Ubuntu server.

I hope you understand my requirement.

Thanks & Regards,

Sam

Answer (score -1):

Here are some resources I have found that may be of help to you. According to these, there are several different options but most of them center around the use of `Samba4` with `OpenLDAP`.

http://linuxdrops.com/install-samba-4-on-centos-rhel-fedora-debian-ubuntu/

http://www.ittables.com/2013/06/samba-4-active-directory-configuration.html

Comment: Where is Here? Whilst links may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.